# How are we supplying the concrete object to a prototype-based factory?

Tags: c++, templates, c++-loki

Loki library provides predefined interfaces for building AbstractFactory pattern. Particularly, I'm interested in prototype-based abstract factory.

Assume that we have a game application which has Abstract Entities:

```
class Soldier{ };
class Monster{ };
class SuperMonster{ };
```

and Concrete Entites:

```
class EasySoldire : public Soldier{ };

class EasyMoster : public Monster{ };

class EasySuperMonster : public SuperMonster{ };
```

And so forth for `Medium` and `Hard`.

Now I want to create Prototype-based easy-level factory.

Here is how it's implemented in Loki (Alexandrescu's Moder C++ Design):

```
template
<
    class AbstractFact,
    template <class, class> class Creator,
    class TList = typename AbstractFact::ProductList
>
class ConcreteFactory;

template <class ConcreteProduct, class Base>
class PrototypeFactoryUnit : public Base
{
    typedef typename Base::ProductList BaseProductList;
protected;
    typedef typename Base::ProductList TailProductList;
public;
    typedef typename Base::ProductList::Head AbstractProduct;
    PrototypeFactoryUnit(AbstractProduct* p = 0)
   :pPrototype_(p) {}
    friend void DoGetPrototype(const PrototypeFactoryUnit& me,
                                AbstractProduct*& pPrototype)
    {
        pPrototype = me.pPrototype_;
    }

    friend void DoSetPrototype(PrototypeFactoryUnit& me,
                               AbstractProduct* pObj)
    {
        me.pPrototype_=pObj;
    }

    template <class U>
    void GetPrototype(AbstractProduct*& p)
    {
        return DoGetPrototype(*this, p);
    }

    template <class U>
    void SetPrototype(U* pObj)
    {
        DoSetPrototype(*this, pObj);
    }

    AbstractProduct* DoCreate(Type2Type<AbstractProduct>)
    {

       assert(pPrototype_);
       return pPrototype_->Clone();
    }
    private:
    AbstractProduct* pPrototype_;
};
```

So the ConcreteFactory will look like:

```
typedef AbstractFactory
<
     TYPELIST_3(Soldier, Monster, SuperMonster)
>
AbstractEnemyFactory;

typedef ConcreteFactory
<
    AbstractEnemyFactory,
    PrototypeFactoryUnit
>
EnemyFactory;
```

Now my question is how can we define `Easy` level factory from that conrete factory?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
EnemyFactory easyFactory;
easyFactory.SetPrototype<EasySoldier>(new EasySoldier);
easyFactory.SetPrototype<EasyMonster>(new EasyMonster);
easyFactory.SetPrototype<EasySuperMonster>(new EasySuperMonster);
Soldier* pSoldier = easyFactory.Create<Soldier>();
Monster* pMonster = easyFactory.Create<Monster>();
SuperMonster* pSuperMonster = easyFactory.Create<SuperMonster>();
```

Be careful, Loki's prototype factory demands all the elements of the class hierarchy to define a Clone method, that is:

```
class Enemy
{
public:
  virtual Enemy* Clone() const = 0;
  virtual ~Enemy() {}
};

class Soldier : public Enemy
{
public:
  virtual Soldier* Clone() const override = 0;
  virtual ~Soldier() {}
};

class EasySoldier : public Soldier
{
public:
  EasySoldier* Clone() const override { return new EasySoldier(*this); };
};
```

and so on.